# Design a CSS element for HOME tab

Tags: javascript

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active">
            <a itemprop="url" href="/">
                <span itemprop="name">Home</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a itemprop="url" href="playing-cards-quote.php">
                <span itemprop="name">Quote Form</span></a></li><li><a itemprop="url" href="custom-playing-cards.php">
                <span itemprop="name">Custom Playing Cards</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a itemprop="url" href="promotional-playing-cards.php">
                <span itemprop="name">Promotional Playing Cards</span>
            </a>
        </li>
```

I am very new to bootstrap, CSS and HTML. Bootstrap is very confusing to me. What could be a possible CSS design for HOME tab? According to me it is:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a { }
```

Is this correct or not? If it is wrong, correct me.

Also suggest some good website and books to learn CSS and bootstrap.

What is the way CSS is placed with bootstrap? How to design CSS using bootstrap?
I know little bit of CSS, but not with bootstrap.

At last please help me with this code to design a CSS Home tab.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp

Comment: @prasad i know this website yaar ...please provide the output of the code i have provided.....All world know w3school website

Answer (score 0):

The term that you're looking for is "selector" as in "what selector do I use to select the home tab" - meaning how you select that node. The "design" would be the styles defined for that node such as width, height, color, etc.

In this case, your selector would be `.active span{/*styles*/}` You don't have to select through each level of CSS as a previous answer showed - it will automatically find children at any level which match.

Comment: i think it may be .active .span {/*styles*/ }    ?

Comment: @DeepakSingh No. The '.' operator is used to select classes. Spans are not a class, but a type of node. You type them as my answer showed.